# Can't retrieve old data from middleware Slim

Tags: html, twig, slim

I have a Middleware directory contains 3 class which is OldInputMiddleware, MiddleWare and ErrorsMiddleware:

```
class Middleware {

protected $container;

public function __construct($container){
    $this->container = $container;
}


class OldInputMiddleware extends Middleware {

public function __invoke($request, $response, $next){

    if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
        $this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('old', $_SESSION['old']);
        $_SESSION['old'] = $request->getParams();
    }

    //always return response with the next occurring
    // request and response
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;
}
```

ErrorsMiddleware is similar to what I had in OldInputMiddleware but it unset sessions variable after retrieving, And in my signup.twig file:

```
<div class="form-group {{ errors.email ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="someone@domain.com" class="form-control" value="{{ old.email }}">
{% if errors.email %}
    <span class="help-block">{{ errors.email | first }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

ErrorsMiddleware works fine and do return relevant error message, but when I try to presists the old data by adding twig comment in value attribute the data wasn't retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for myself, it was a silly mistake at this line of statement:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['errors']))
```

Should be $_SESSION['old'] instead of $_SESSION['errors']

Answer (score 0):

You can delete if statement. It is not necessary.

You can write as follow without if statement.

```
$this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('old', $_SESSION['old']);
$_SESSION['old'] = $request->getParams();
```